# Property not found exception in JSP EL

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, el

Very annoying. Don't know why this error is coming. In the below code

```
NOTE:

if I only use <td>${user.id}</td> than its printing id properly but on ${user.username} property generating error. See below JSP page code.

If I use below code in JSP page like to test than I get all the objects and properties


<c:forEach var="user" items="${users}" varStatus="i">
    <tr>
        <td>${users[i.index]}</td>
    </tr>                       
</c:forEach>

Result:

User[id=1,username=u1,password=p1,firstname=f1,lastname=l1,dob=2012-07-01,age=40]
User[id=2,username=u2,password=p2,firstname=f2,lastname=l2,dob=2012-07-02,age=39]
User[id=3,username=u3,password=p3,firstname=f3,lastname=l3,dob=2012-07-03,age=38]
```

**ERROR:**

```
09:49:49,047 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/crud_jsp_servlet_cdi_jdbc_tagfile].[jsp]] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception: javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: The class 'com.myapp.dao.User' does not have the property 'username'.
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getBeanProperty(BeanELResolver.java:661) [jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:290) [jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:175) [jboss-el-api_2.2_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:169) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:189) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:935) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.admin.UserList_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(UserList_jsp.java:137)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.admin.UserList_jsp.access$1(UserList_jsp.java:114)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.admin.UserList_jsp$Helper.invoke1(UserList_jsp.java:215)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.admin.UserList_jsp$Helper.invoke(UserList_jsp.java:240)
    at org.apache.jsp.tag.web.layout_tag.doTag(layout_tag.java:120)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.admin.UserList_jsp._jspx_meth_tags_005flayout_005f0(UserList_jsp.java:96)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.admin.UserList_jsp._jspService(UserList_jsp.java:69)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
```

***JSP Page:***

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="tags" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags"%>

<tags:layout path="${pageContext.request.contextPath}">
    <jsp:attribute name="search">
        <tags:search />
    </jsp:attribute>
    <jsp:body>
        <div class="mainDiv">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>UserName</th>
                        <th>Password</th>
                        <th>FirstName</th>
                        <th>LastName</th>
                        <th>Date of Birth</th>
                        <th>Age</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <c:forEach var="user" items="${users}">
                        <tr>
                            <td>${user.id}</td>
                            <td>${user.username}</td>
                            <td>${user.password}</td>
                            <td>${user.firstname}</td>
                            <td>${user.lastname}</td>
                            <td>${user.dob}</td>
                            <td>${user.age}</td>
                            <td><a href="#"><i class="icon-edit"></i></a> <a href="#"><i
                                    class="icon-trash"></i></a></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </jsp:body>
</tags:layout>
```

***User.java***

```
package com.myapp.dao;

import java.sql.Date;


public class User {

    private Long id;
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String firstname;
    private String lastname;
    private Date dob;
    private int age;

    public User(){
    };

    public User(Long id, String username, String password, String firstname, String lastname, Date dob, int age){

        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
        this.dob = dob;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public Long getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getUserName(){
        return username;
    }

    public void setUserName(String username){
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword(){
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password){
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName(){
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstname){
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastName(){
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastname){
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public Date getDob(){
        return dob;
    }

    public void setDob(Date dob){
        this.dob = dob;
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age){
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getFullName(){
        return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname;
    }

}
```

***Selvlet:***

```
List<User> users = null;
        userDAO = new UserDAOJDBC();

        users = userDAO.listUsers();
        request.setAttribute("users", users);

        String path = "/WEB-INF/admin/UserList.jsp";
        getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(path).forward(request, response);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Case matters for Java Bean properties. In EL you try to access property `username`, but in bean you have `getUserName/setUserName`. Use `getUsername/setUsername` (lowercase 'n') instead.

Comment: ${user.userName} this worked and all other cases failed. Why userName worked as I haven't declare any property like that in User DTO?

Comment: Yes, that should also work. Your problem was that EL didn't matched to property name. Now user.userName matches to method names (getUserName/setUserName) in User class. I suggested to modify bean instead, because usually you have property called 'username', not the 'user name'. But it comes to functionality, both solutions make it work, as long as result is that you use same case consistently.

Comment: thanks but my method names (getUserName/setUserName) are like this and UserName not worked. This way I need to keep testing for properties to use them in EL. Is there any proper way to do it right so I use it easily in EL?

Comment: And UserName also should not work. If method name is getUserName, then name of the property in EL is userName, and for example not UserName.